# Ignoring axios error for invalid certificates when creating a vscode extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, axios, ssl-certificate, vscode-extensions

I am currently working on a Visual Studio Code extension that makes HTTPS GET requests and I am trying to ignore invalid certificates e.g. expired certificates.

**Here is a very simple script in typescript that works:**

```
import * as https from "https";
import axios from "axios";

try {
    const test = async () => {
        await axios.get( 
            'https://expired.badssl.com/',
            
            {
                httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
                    rejectUnauthorized: false
                })
            }
        );
    };
    test();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

As expected, when I compile the file and run it, it returns nothing and if I change `rejectUnauthorized` to `true`, it logs an expired certificate error.

However, when I create a simple typescript extension as described in https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension with `yo code` and make a similar axios request, it **gives a certificate has expired error regardless of the parameter** given to`rejectUnauthorized`

**Similar typescript code as above made with `yo code` template:**

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as https from "https";
import axios from "axios";

export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('nameOfExtension.helloWorld', async () => {
        try {
            await axios.get(
                'https://expired.badssl.com/', 
                {
                    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
                        rejectUnauthorized: false
                    })
                }
            );
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

(where `nameOfExtension` is the name of the extension in `package.json`)

***How the extension works:** User opens up the command palette (cmd+P on mac) and runs the 'hello world' command which runs the axios request. If it works, nothing happens, otherwise the error message is printed to the console.*

One way I found in which I could make the extension ignore the certificate is by adding in the line of code `https.globalAgent.options.rejectUnauthorized = false` which sets the globalAgent to always be false.

But setting this globally is **not** something I wish to do and **I would like the `rejectUnauthorized` to work for a single instance**.

I was wondering if anyone knew why the `rejectUnauthorized` method shown in the example would not work on vscode?

Here are my thoughts:

- Could it be something to do with the environment?
- Is the global setting applied automatically when the extension is run and is it overriding the the local setting that I apply?

Additional information:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@types/vscode": "^1.61.0",
        "@types/glob": "^7.1.4",
        "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
        "@types/node": "14.x",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.31.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.31.1",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "glob": "^7.1.7",
        "mocha": "^9.1.1",
        "typescript": "^4.4.3",
        "@vscode/test-electron": "^1.6.2"
},
"dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.4",
        "https": "^1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Is anyone else getting this problem when recreating this, or is it just me i.e. could it be to do with some other configuration?

Comment: What if you create an instance of axios using `axios.create([config])` and put httpsAgent as a default config and try to get method of newly created instance?

Comment: @Max unfortunately this solution doesn't work

Comment: This issue has still not been resolved

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a promise?

Otherwise you can use it like this:

```
const axios = require('axios');


return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

   axios
       .get('https://expired.badssl.com/', {
             responseType: 'arraybuffer',
             responseEncoding: 'binary'
       }).catch(e => e + 'Get reqeust failed.')
       .then(response => {
            const data = response.data
       })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:

```
let URL = "your_URL";
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
let response = await axios.get(URL); //this one should success
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = undefined;

//Since we already set it back to undefined, the following one should fail. 
// Hence we create a temporary workaround for a specific request:
let response2 = await axios.get(URL); //this one should fail
```